# Get contact details on rowclick

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to get the contact details when i click on name column.
The name column contains the contact when i click on them i need its details.

Can anybody help!!

**Visualforce page**

```
   <apex:page controller="AccountContactController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Name">
            <apex:actionFunction name="change" action="{!refreshContactList}" reRender="pbt" />            
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedAccId}" size="1" onchange="change()" title="Accounts">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountNames}" />
            </apex:selectList><br/><br/>
            <b>Related Contacts</b>          
            <apex:pageblockTable title="Contacts" value="{!Conlist}" var="Sc" id="pbt">     
            <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="save" hideOnEdit="edit"/>                 
                <apex:column value="{!Sc.name}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!Sc.phone}"/>                       
            <apex:commandLink value="{!Sc.name}"/>
            <apex:pageblockSection >
                <apex:actionSupport action="{!refreshContactDetails}" event="onclick" rerender="detail" status="mystatus">
                    <apex:param name="cid" assignTo="{!selectedConId}" value="{!Sc.id}"/>
                     <apex:detail id="detail" relatedList="true" subject="{!Sc.id}"/>
                </apex:actionSupport>
               </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageblockTable> 
           <center> <apex:commandButton value="Edit"  id="edit"/></center>&nbsp;
           <center><apex:commandButton value="Save" id="save" action="{!Save}"/></center>      
        </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
Public with sharing class AccountContactController {   
    Public Id selectedAccId{get;set;} 
    public integer phone{get;set;}
    Public List<Contact> SelectedContacts{get;set;}
    Public List<Contact> Conlist{get;set;}    
    Public List<SelectOption> getAccountNames() {
        List<SelectOption> accOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
        system.debug(selectedAccId);
        accOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
        for(Account acc : [select Id,name from Account ] ) {
            accOptions.add(new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.name));
        }
        return accOptions;
    }
      public List<Contact> SelectedContacts(){
         return Conlist;
      }
    public void refreshContactList(){
        Conlist = new List<Contact>();
        Conlist = [select name,phone from Contact where Accountid=: selectedAccId];
    }
   Public PageReference Save() {
        update Conlist;
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apex:actionSupport` on `apex:column` to capture the click event on table row. Pass the contact Id back to Controller with the help of `apex:param`. Now you can fetch the details in `refreshContactDetails()` and pass it back to the vf page to render the contact details.

Vf Page

```
.........
.........
    <apex:pageblockTable title="Contacts" value="{!Conlist}" var="Sc" id="pbt">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="save" hideOnEdit="edit"/>     
        <apex:column>
            <apex:actionSupport action="{!refreshContactDetails}" event="onclick" rerender="detail" status="mystatus">
                <apex:param name="cid" assignTo="{!selectedConId}" value="{!Sc.id}"/>
            </apex:actionSupport>
            <apex:outputText value="{!Sc.name}"/>                    
        </apex:column>        
        <apex:column value="{!Sc.phone}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
.......
.......
```

Controller

```
..........
..........
Public Id selectedConId{get;set;} 
..........
..........
Public PageReference refreshContactDetails() {
    System.debug('Selected Contact : '+selectedConId);
    return null;
}
..........
..........
```

> Update

To get the contact link as hyperlink use `<apex:outputLink` replace the line

`<apex:outputText value="{!Sc.name}"/>` with the below line

```
<apex:outputLink onclick="return false;" >{!Sc.name}</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Thanks Saroj for your reply..its working but i am not getting any link on contact name

Comment: Check my update. If this answer has solved your question you can use the check mark next to it to mark it as such. That will help others who are looking at it to locate the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Deepak I think this is what you are looking for**

**Controller**

```
    Public with sharing class AccountContactController {   
    Public Id selectedAccId{get;set;} 
    public integer phone{get;set;}
    Public List<Contact> SelectedContacts{get;set;}
    Public List<Contact> Conlist{get;set;} 
    Public List<SelectOption> getAccountNames() {
        List<SelectOption> accOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
        system.debug(selectedAccId);
        accOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
        for(Account acc : [select Id,name from Account ] ) {
            accOptions.add(new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.name));
        }
        return accOptions;
    }
      public List<Contact> SelectedContacts(){
         return Conlist;
      }
    public void refreshContactList(){
        Conlist = new List<Contact>();
        Conlist = [select name,phone from Contact where Accountid=: selectedAccId];
    }
   Public PageReference Save() {
        update Conlist;
        return null;
    }
}
```

**VisualForce**

```
    <apex:page controller="AccountContactController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account Name">
        <apex:actionFunction name="change" action="{!refreshContactList}" reRender="pbt" />            
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedAccId}" size="1" onchange="change()" title="Accounts">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AccountNames}" />
        </apex:selectList><br/><br/>
        <b>Related Contacts</b>   
        <apex:detail id="detail" rerender="Click"/>
        <apex:pageblockTable title="Contacts" value="{!Conlist}" var="Sc" id="pbt">
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="save" hideOnEdit="edit"/>     
        <apex:column>
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!Sc.Id}">{!Sc.name}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>        
        <apex:column value="{!Sc.phone}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>   
        <center> <apex:commandButton value="Edit"  id="edit"/></center>&nbsp;
       <center><apex:commandButton value="Save" id="save" action="{!Save}"/></center>      
    </apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If it solves your problem mark it as answer.  **Thanks!!**

Comment: If you need any explanation, you can ask any time...feel free to ask

Comment: HI Saran, thanks for your reply..But the thing is after i click the link i am not getting details

Comment: It is working perfectly and I have tested it. What's the problem you are facing please share